# Audio files shared by bluetooth read-only

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

In my app, a user can buy and download an audio file from Itunes.

I would like other people (with a IOS, or Android) to listen to this audio file on their own smartphone, using a Bluetooth connection.

Is it possible to develop these kinds of functionalities? Where could I find some information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find information, just do an Internet search for this:

"Multipeer Connectivity (audio) Streaming"

I am suggesting the MC framework because it supports streaming and connecting with other iOS devices.  MC does not allow you to specify whether it uses wifi or Bluetooth but it gets the job done.

EDIT: Sorry, this will only work with iOS devices.